# Paramiko SFTP : list content to a file

Tags: python, paramiko

Trying to write list content to remote file.Below is my code

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
conn = ssh.connect(hostname='agnel-1', port=22, username='root', password='pass')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("hostname")
host = stdout.readlines()
diam_hostname = host[0].strip('\n')
gx_list = ["--hostname                                      {0}".format(diam_hostname),
           "--hostrealm                                     BNG-1.com",
           "--auth-app-id                                   16777238",
           "--verbose                                        1",
           "--port                                          3868",
           "--dictionary                                    r8-gx-standard",
           "--supported-vendor-id                           10415",
           "--supported-vendor-id                           8164",
           "--supported-vendor-id                           12645",
           "--gx-command 0",
           "--charging-rule-name                            prepaid",
           "--charg-service-id                              1",
           "--rating-grp                                    1",
           "--preemptive                                    1",
           "--disable-sctp"]
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
try:
    f = sftp.open('{0}/Diam.gx'.format(self.inputs['minidiam_path']), 'w')
except IOError:
    print "Failed to Open the file for writing"
for s in gx_list:
    f.write(s + '\n')
f.close()
```

Getting Error with variable f

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment
```

Did'nt get any Error with sftp opening the file though.

Thanks,
Agnel.

Comment: Are you getting that error along eith a IOError?

Comment: Not getting any IOError

Answer (score 0):

Are you also seeing `""Failed to Open the file for writing""` printed out? If your code raises a `IOError`, once the exception is handled since you are not returning, it executes the remaining statements. For example the following code raises the error `"NameError: name 'f' is not defined"`

try:

```
    raise KeyError
```

except KeyError:

```
    print "Keyerror"
```

print f